# Incapaz de conectar al servidor localhost con mssql_connect

Tags: php, sql-server

Buen día a todos, espero podáis echarme una mano con el error:
"Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: localhost"

Antes de explicarles el problema les relato las circunstancias:

- Mi version de php es la 5.6.32 y me veo en la obligación de conectar con esta función obsoleta debido a que el servidor trabaja con ella.
- Mi Base de datos es SQL-Server 2014
- Los brackets (variables host,user,pw) son los correctos [comprobado porque funcionan con otros tipos de conexiones]

verán:

1. he descargado esta libreria: php_dblibx86.dll. de la pag. (https://wiki.processmaker.com/3.3/Database_Connections/MSSQL)
2. he copiado la libreria en la carpeta xampp/php/ext
3. la he activado desde el archivo php.ini.
4. he comprobado que la libreria esté activa mediante phpinfo() en el cual muestra "MSSQL" - MSSQL Support enabled / Active Persistent Links   0/ Active Links 0 / Library version FreeTDS

luego en otro archivo he usado este código:

```
<?php
     $dbhost = "localhost";
     $dbusuario = "sa";
     $dbpassword= "12345";
     $db = "centroidiomas";    
     $cnx = mssql_connect($dbhost, $dbusuario, $dbpassword) or die("Error de Conexion.");
         mssql_select_db($db,$cnx) or die("Error seleccionando la base de datos.");
?>
```

y termina por botar este error:

> Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: localhost in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\idiomas141119\certis\conexion.php on line 6 Error de
>   Conexion.

Hice un var_dump($cnx) el cual me da por resultado "bool(false)"

he activado la linea: "mssql.secure_connection = On" en el archivo php.ini y aún asi no conecta

Agradeceré todos los comentarios posibles.

Comment: Tambien descargaste los archivos msodbcsql.msi y sqlncli.msi?

Comment: No estoy muy seguro pero yo acabo de probar tu codigo hace unos minutos y se ejecuta normal. Pienso que quiza eso este ayudando si deseas descargalo

Comment: Lee [la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mssql-connect.php). En los ejemplos ellos dicen que para `$dbhost` tienes que poner algo así: `tuComputer\tuInstancia`, donde `tuComputer` es el nombre de tu computadora y `tuInstancia` es el nombre de la instancia de SQL Server. Pero yo veo que estás poniendo `localhost` sin más ¿?  Prueba así y dinos si funciona, si ocurre el mismo error, u otro tipo de error. Dinos además qué sistema operativo tienes.

Comment: Lee también lo que dice sobre el parámetro **servername**: *«El servidor MS SQL. También puede incluir un número de puerto, p.e. hostname:port (Linux), o hostname,port (Windows).»*

Comment: Ya he instalado msodbcsql.msi y sqlncli.msi y sigue habiendo el mismo error
He probado con el código de la guía:
$server = 'DESKTOP-MFPCKHR\SQLEXPRESS';
 $link = mssql_connect($server, 'sa', '12345');
 if (!$link) {
     die('Algo fue mal mientras se conectaba a MSSQL');
 }
y me da el mismo error que antes
he probado poniendole un puerto 127.0.0.1:80 en la variable server y aún nada

Hasta pienso que estoy usando mal aquella libreria.
Capo, ¿podrías fijarte las librerías que tienes activas en php.ini y de ser posible la fuente de donde puedo descargarlo?